# How do I pass php form data to an angular2 app?

Tags: php, angular, express, post

I'm still quite new to angular2/4 so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I am trying to update a booking process and we are doing this with angular2/4. Currently the booking process starts on a php website, once some basic information is filled out the angular app is supposed to take over. What I'm not sure of is how I'm supposed to take the form data from PHP and receive that data in my angular app.

There is an express.js back end for the angular app, but I don't understand how I would be able to post from the PHP site and return the result to the angular app.

Again sorry, I'm still new to angular so I'm not sure how I should approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an API (http://localhost:8080/bookings/) in your existing PHP application which your angular app can access via a GET/POST request using angulars HTTP client. https://angular.io/guide/http.

Or

2. Alternatively, use the express backend to talk to the MySql DB / Or other DB that your php application is using. Use express as an API similar to the above or simply render the page with the data obtained from the DB. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html